# 404 Error When Attempting To Access File in Folder on Apache when File Exists in Folder

Tags: apache, web, http-status-code-404

I am using Apache for a web app. When the user signs up, a new folder is created for them so that their dashboard is personalised. When I do a test user sign-up and check if the folder exists in FTP it always shows up containing all the necessary files. But when I navigate to the folder in my browser window it returns a 404 error message saying the page cannot be found. There is an index file in each folder so it should show up automatically as I understand it. I have tried changing the permissions on the created folders but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I have also added the following to the Apache directives:

```
Alias /web "/var/www/web"
Options +Indexes
AllowOverride None
```

However, this does not solve the problem either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your folder or file name contain spaces or special characters? Were they placed under a accessible folder by apache? What file permission is given to files?

Comment: Hi Naresh. Thanks for responding. Folders and file names contain no spaces or special characters. File permissions given to files are 0644 and folders within the folder are 0755. How would I find out if they have been placed in an accessible folder by apache? I am using ispconfig.

Comment: Is this all you have in Apache conf/.htaccess? Are there any rewrite rules set up?

Comment: Yes, there are also some rewrite rules to hide file extensions:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    </IfModule>